# Why are there cows on my spaceship?

Tags: the-outer-worlds

When returning to my reliable Unreliable, I went to go tinker on some weaponry and was greeted with this sight:

[image: cows]

This is actually the second time this has happened and I went in and out of my ship at least a dozen times over the next 6 hours, but never saw these Wooly Cows again, nor could I find any trace of them *anywhere* on my ship. I’m incredibly baffled and have no idea where these are coming from nor why this is happening... what is going on?

Comment: I only noticed the cows when ADA complained about "shipments of fertilizer". I thought I had accidentally accepted a quest for delivering cow crap...

Comment: @Nolonar yeah I figured that somehow I had accidentally brought this onto myself and I was extremely confused. Even more so when I left and returned and they were nowhere to be found

Comment: Unrelated question, but why does that screen shot seem so *dark*?  I have seen this exact same problem on several games over the years that I have played across multiple machines.

Comment: @Michael no clue. Honestly, all of the screenshots I’ve taken in menus and buildings in this game have been extra dark. Haven’t tried during the daytime outside or anything, but...

Comment: @Michael: I think it's that many games configure a custom display gamma value (higher than the usual 1.0), and this only affects GPU video output but not the stored pixels that a screenshot captures. (I don't have the game and don't know what setting it uses, but e.g. [with 1.4 it would look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbFsO.jpg).)

Comment: How else will you get fresh steak?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This is an easter egg referencing the sci-fi show *Firefly*. This area can randomly show crew interacting with each other and one of these random scenes is the cows that reference Firefly.

As you play through *The Outer Worlds* you will be running into more *Firefly* references, it's likely that the show served as inspiration to the creators in the game.

Screenshot from the *Firefly* TV show featuring the cow scene:
[image: firefly cows]

And here's the clip from the show:

(starts at 39 seconds)

Comment: Ah, see, I haven’t seen Firefly, so this went over my head, I thought I was just hallucinating or something, haha. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @Vemonus You should watch it, it's incredible.

Comment: @FoxMcCloud Concur - Season 1 is great and I can't wait for season 2....

Comment: @Criggie *googles* Pretty sure that Firefly season 2 rumors were an April Fool's Day joke.

Comment: @nick012000 It's coming out about the same time as Half Life 3.

Comment: @Darren No, I heard it was going to be released alongside the final *Game of Thrones* book. Some kind of crossover deal, I think.

Comment: @Criggie While you're waiting can I perhaps suggest watching Serenity? I heard it ties in pretty well with the Firefly universe

Comment: @MindSwipe I love Serentiy, it's a great film. I also hate it too though.